# Can not read from inputstream in FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write

Tags: c#, excel, stream, epplus

I am trying to read a excel file using

```
 using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            ExcelWorksheet worksheet;
                            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(stream))
```

actually I am trying to add a worksheet in existing excel file so that's why I am using append , and when I used filemode.create then it is overtiring my existing tab with the new one so what should I do?

Comment: What is meant by "new tab"? Do you mean a new worksheet?

Comment: yes new worksheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the following code and it will add a new worksheet to your current file:

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("YourFile.xlsx");
using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("YourNewSheet");
    p.Save();
}
```

Comment: this will overwrite my existing working sheet which is in first position.

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 How can that be? I have created a File 'YourFile.xlxs' and added a sheet to it and filled it with value. Then I have run this code. It creates a new sheet and keeps the other sheet with its values. Have you installed the latest version of EPPlus?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same actions easily with Microsoft open xml
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-get-worksheet-information-from-a-package